# Why doesn't <br /> work properly in React?

Tags: html, reactjs

This is my code

```
<div className='product'>
    <img className='productImg' src={this.props.image} alt='of person'></img>
    <div style={{float:'left'}}>{this.props.name}</div>
    <br />
    <div style={{float: 'left'}}>${this.props.price}</div>
    <br />
    <div style={{color: this.pickRatingColor(this.props.rating), float:'right'}}>{this.props.rating}/5</div>
    

</div>
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO7ct.png)

(I just used a  random screenshot i had for the picture so don't judge)

The thing that I simply can't wrap my head around is why the price doesn't go below the name even though I added a break. I would appreciate it if someone could explain why this happens and how I can fix it.
Thank you!

Comment: might be because of using `float`, flex/grid are better for layouts

Comment: Use flexbox instead of float

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand why you are using float ;
it will be fixed if you delete your styles that added in name and price div;